# Memory Increases When Merging and Playing Audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, avfoundation, core-foundation

I'm trying to merge multiple pieces of audio into one simultaneous sound and then play it. I can merge and play, but my app's memory usage keeps increasing over time.

Looking online, it seems like there's ARC/memory issues with AVPlayer.

I've added all relevant code below for setting up the files, merging them and then playing them.

**Setting up sound files**

```
- (void) setUpSoundFiles {
    AVURLAsset *songAsset = nil;
    AVAssetTrack *sourceAudioTrack = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSoundsToMerge; i++){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[@(i) stringValue] ofType:@"mp3"]];

        songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        sourceAudioTrack = [[songAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

        [songTracks insertObject:sourceAudioTrack atIndex:i];
        [songAssets insertObject:[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil] atIndex:i];
        //[sourceAudioTrack.asset cancelLoading];
    }


}
```

**Merging Sound Files**

```
- (void) mergeAudio: (AVMutableComposition *)composition{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSoundsToMerge; i++) {

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];


        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL ok = NO;

        CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1);
        CMTime trackDuration = ((AVURLAsset *)[songAssets objectAtIndex:i]).duration;

        CMTimeRange tRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, trackDuration);

        //Set Volume
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
        [trackMix setVolume:0.8f atTime:startTime];
        [audioMixParams addObject:trackMix];

        //Insert audio into track
        ok = [track insertTimeRange:tRange ofTrack:(AVAssetTrack *)[songTracks objectAtIndex:i] atTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) error:&error];
        [((AVAssetTrack *)[songTracks objectAtIndex:i]).asset cancelLoading];
    }
}
```

**Playing Sound Files**

```
- (void) playSounds {

    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    audioMixParams = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];


    [self mergeAudio:composition];

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    audioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithArray:audioMixParams];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];


    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

    [playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
    [player play]; }
```